# Why does @Transactional not work, but writing it manually does work

Tags: jpa, jta

I am currently trying some things in JPA, and seem to have hit a block that i cannot figure out and cant find online.

I am trying to retrieve a list of the customers in de PostgreSQL DB, this can be done by writing the transaction manually or using the JTA @Transactional annotation. However the manual implementation is working, and the `@Transactional` is not.

I have written the manual transaction like so:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.CustomerDto;
import com.example.demo.mapper.CustomerMapper;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
//import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import models.Customer;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomerRepository {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    public List<CustomerDto> findAllManual() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-postgres");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Customer> customers = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c", Customer.class)
                .getResultList();
        List<CustomerDto> customerDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        customers.forEach(t -> customerDtos.add(CustomerMapper.toDto(t)));
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt entity manager: " + entityManager);
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt customers: " + customers);
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt customersDTO: " + customerDtos);
        entityManager.close();
        return customerDtos;
    }
```

And this returns my list properly. Except the following does not.

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.CustomerDto;
import com.example.demo.mapper.CustomerMapper;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
//import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import models.Customer;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa-postgres")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<CustomerDto> findAll() {
                List customers = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c", Customer.class)
                .getResultList();
        List<CustomerDto> customerDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        customers.forEach(t -> customerDtos.add(CustomerMapper.toDto((Customer) t)));
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt entity manager: " + em);
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt customers: " + customers);
        System.out.println("Komt hier wel. Print evt customersDTO: " + customerDtos);
        return customerDtos;
    }

}
```

This returns an empty list.

What I think the problem is: the `@Transactional` method does not connect to the DB which s why is returns an empty list. But I can't seem to figure out why that is.

The `persistence.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa-postgres">

        <class>models.Customer</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/filmland" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So it should use the same "jpa-postgres" as the manual transaction does the sys outs print the following.

Manual method:

```
16:20:02,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: 
16:20:02,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     select
16:20:02,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.id,
16:20:02,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.email,
16:20:02,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.password 
16:20:02,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     from
16:20:02,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         customer c1_0
16:20:02,347 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt entity manager: SessionImpl(394828776<open>)
16:20:02,348 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt customers: [Customer(id=1, email=kees@kees.com, password=mooiman), Customer(id=2, email=jan@jan.com, password=mooieding)]
16:20:02,348 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt customersDTO: [com.example.demo.dto.CustomerDto@52fb491a, com.example.demo.dto.CustomerDto@76e5d921]
```

The `@Transactional` method:

```
[2023-11-16 04:14:59,878] Artifact demo:war exploded: Deploy took 2,428 milliseconds
16:16:36,579 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: 
16:16:36,579 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     select
16:16:36,579 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.id,
16:16:36,580 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.email,
16:16:36,580 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         c1_0.password 
16:16:36,580 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     from
16:16:36,580 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         customer c1_0
16:16:36,586 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt entity manager: org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager@2d71f100
16:16:36,587 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt customers: []
16:16:36,587 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Komt hier wel. Print evt customersDTO: []
```

Anyone able to help me understand why this is happening and why the Transactional is implement in the wrong way by me ?

Comment: if no errors occur it might kinda work. You could try to execute some query like "select 1+2". But the query is logged so I assume its executed. The setup for transational might just create a new empty database schema? As the schema generation is on. Who inserts those customers?

Comment: It is kinda working just that with the ```transactional``` and not writing it manually it returns an empty list. The DB was setup once with 2 Customers that got saved trough a save transaction (that was manual aswell). Both are in the DB and the wierd thing is. 
Manually it does return both Customers.
When the ```transactional``` is added (And the manual is removed) it returns an empty list.

Comment: "@Transactional" is a container annotation, not a JPA one. If you aren't seeing your EntityManager take part in the container managed transaction, it is because you can't use the same context in both container managed and locally managed mechanisms - not when you are telling JPA to connect to the database directly with the jdbc.url connection. Container transaction control require that the container also control the datasource, so that your EntityManager instance uses the same connection as the one the transaction is with. Turn on logging and you will likely see warnings on Persistence deploy